# Pasar un valor superior a 1000 de un input a otro con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Hola tengo un value que recoge la información de otro otro value mediante jquery, lo gracioso de todo es que si me paso de 999 el segundo value no recoge la información...

**Inputs HTML**

```
<input  id="total_todo" name="total_todo" type="decimal" placeholder="0" value="{{$total}}"> //ESTE INPUT RECOGE POR EJEMPLO 1000
<input class="input form-control" type="number" name="impPago" id="impPago-rePago" required=""> ESTE RECOGE LO QUE HAYA EN INPUT tota_todo
```

**Jquery**

```
        total_todo=$("#total_todo").val();
        alert(total_todo);
        $("#impPago-rePago").val(total_todo); //SI total_todo es menor de 1000 si que recibo los datos si no no los recibo....
```

Answer (score 0):

No se como tengas implementado tu codigo, pero hacerlo utilizando un evento click es muy sencillo.

```
<input  id="total_todo" name="total_todo" type="decimal" placeholder="0" value="{{$total}}"> //ESTE INPUT RECOGE POR EJEMPLO 1000
<input class="input form-control" type="number" name="impPago" id="impPago-rePago" required=""> ESTE RECOGE LO QUE HAYA EN INPUT tota_todo

<button id="btn">
  Enviar
</button>
```

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    total_todo=$("#total_todo").val();
        alert(total_todo);
        $("#impPago-rePago").val(total_todo);
});
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Eso lo tengo claro amigo de todos modos el error lo tenía en el redondeo de PHP

Comment: Después lo comento bien la solución